# Ember and SVG: views not rendered when array controller content changes

Tags: svg, ember.js

I am using Ember and SVG to create a timeline. Below is a link to a jsfiddle I have created (simplified from original code):

http://jsfiddle.net/karlguillotte/UgeFk/

There is no problem once the calendar is rendered for the first time, as well as when I modified an attribute (see init function). However, there are some issues when I set the events collection (Error: NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: DOM Exception 9 is thrown).

Off course, I could use d3 to render those rectangles, however I would like to take advantage of the binding mechanism offered by Ember. The error is probably related with the *script* tag used by Ember to manage bindings.

Any idea how this could work using Ember and SVG only?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
App.eventsController.set('content', [{ start: 50, end: 100 }]);

{ start: 50, end: 100 } !== Em.Object.create({ start: 50, end: 100 });
```

Did you mean:

```
App.eventsController.set('content', [Em.Object.create({ start: 50, end: 100 })]);
```

or simply:

```
App.eventsController.clear().pushObject(Em.Object.create({ start: 25, end: 100 }));
```

---

```
App.eventsController.set('content', [{ start: 50, end: 100 }]);//will work
//but you cannot use set/get etc on the object later as its a pure js object.
```

`SVG` is kind of strict in most ways, needs `setAttributeNS` in most places, takes all textNodes, so making a template engine manage things inside SVG is hard.

One workaround for now will be to use separate positioned `SVG` elements and restructure like:

```
App.EventView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'svg',
    templateName: 'event',
    ....
});
```

---

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="event"><g><rect {{bindAttr x="view.x"}} {{bindAttr y="view.y"}} {{bindAttr width="view.width"}} {{bindAttr height="view.height"}}></rect></g></script>
```

---

```
svg.ember-view{position:absolute;top:10px;left:10px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UgeFk/4/

http://jsfiddle.net/UgeFk/5/

I did something similar on a dropped project:

```
{{#each groups}}
  {{#view App.groupView groupBinding="this"}}
    <svg class="migration" height="568" width="1024">
      <g transform="translate(0,0)">
        {{countryMarkers}}
        <path {{bindAttr style="bezierStyle"}} {{bindAttr d="bezierPath"}} class="curve" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

I would also love to hear if there is a better solution without unbinding or manual templating.

Comment: SVG only requires setAttributeNS for links, everything else can use setAttribute. Elements on the other hand do require createElementNS.